# Java multiple interface inhertirance and value passing

Tags: java, android, class, interface, java-native-interface

I am planning to make large class in Java that should implement multiple listener interfaces and send it to native code. Point of it is to handle events from all kinds of "views".

How common is this practice in Java?

Another question is that if such class is created, does passing it to multiple objects such as `button.setOnClickListener(class);` create new instances, or passes reference/pointer to it?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to consider using multiple classes, one for each listener implementation. You would be passing a reference, not creating a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

As Eric said, it's cleaner to make separate classes, perhaps nested in the main one if you want to see the code there. (Though that's a sure way of creating a many hundred lines long class, which is not exactly easy to maintain..)

As for reference vs new instance: if you're doing it correctly, you shouldn't have to create more than one object in general, you'd just reference that one.

Also, in your sample code, passing a variable named "class" seems strange, though you probably just didn't consider that - you'd be passing an instance, not a class.

Comment: Yeah should have wrote instance_name instead of class, thank you:)